# Is there reference material for dictionary abbreviations used in the first half of the 20th century?

Tags: abbreviations

I have a lot of abbreviations that I can't work out the meaning of from an old etymological dictionary and I'm looking for a reference that will explain them all.

I have a copy of an etymological dictionary about the Sinhala language, written in English by [Wilhelm Geiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Geiger) (a German), published in 1941. It has a table at the front to explain the abbreviations used for each language's name used but not for the different parts of speech.

E.g. (italicised text transliterated from Sinhala into English):

*pahan*, *pasan* **a. pprt.** pleased, glad

*temanavaa* **v., prt.** *temuvaa* to wet, moisten

*mala* **s., st. f.** *mal* flower

I have highlighted the abbreviations in bold. I have omitted the actual etymologies because they are not relevant to my question.

I can work out that **a.** is adjective and **v.** is verb and he also uses **adv.** for adverb but he uses **s.** for nouns (the majority of the entries are nouns) and **st. f.** and **st. ff.** for single and multiple plural forms respectively (i.e. one *mala*, two *mal* using the example above). I'm guessing that he's using the same convension as **p**=page and **pp**=pages for the "f"s, **st. f.**=one plural form, **st. ff.**=multiple plural forms. I have no idea what **prt.** and **a. pprt.** mean. It must have been common enough knowledge for his intended audience that he didn't need to explain these terms. Could it be that even though he has written the dictionary in English that he is using the German abbreviations (**s.**=substantiv noun)?

Where can I find out what all these (and the others I haven't mentioned) actually mean?

Comment: Would pprt be past participle?

Comment: My guesses: prt. = participle; pprt. = past [or present]  participle; a. pprt. = adjective and past/present participle; ff. = (and the) following [or perhaps *folios*]; f. = feminine; s. = substantive [which is a legitimate alternative designation for a noun in English, not only in German]; st. = stanza. If you can't decipher the abbreviations sufficiently, perhaps a university with a department that covers Sinhalese may be able to help: I would assume they'd be familiar with this particular work.

Comment: I've always associated "participle" with verbs but Wikipedia says "A participle is a form of a verb that is used in a sentence to modify a noun or noun phrase and thus plays a role similar to that of an adjective or adverb (some languages have distinct forms for adverbial participles and adjectival participles)." so I think @ErikKowal is correct about this. "f" and "ff" are definitely not feminine (_tenē_ **s.** son, **st. f.** _tena_ sons) or folio(s). Stanza doesn't make sense in this context for **st.** (a form that's only used in stanzas?). I know enough to recognise that they're plural.

Comment: **pron. pers. 2nd pl.** is personal pronoun, 2nd person plural but what does the bit immediately following in the same entry for a different spelling mean? **obl. c.**? Obsolete? Obligatory? See second and third examples above for differing spellings for grammatical cases. If these were not common English abbreviations in 1940, at least within grammar/linguistics why was there no explanatory table? You may be right that I need to ask someone who knows Sinhala and can describe it in English grammatical terminology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_grammatical_cases Maybe **obl. c.** is Oblique case: all-round case; any situation except nominative or vocative. It's so hard to understand without a single source that explains them all!

Comment: The hyperlink does not work, but if you type "Kannada English Dictionary abbreviation" in google books, you'l find a good page of abreviation explanation from a similar dicionnary.

Comment: @JoBedard Thank you for the suggestion. The book I found was _A Kannada-English Dictionary_ by Ferdinand Kittel but I can't find any matching abbreviations in the table of that book. Was that the one you meant?

Comment: @cj dennis yes that's the one, but for some reason when I copy the link toward Google Books it does not work. I'll post a print screen as an answer.

Comment: @CJ Dennis try this link http://books.google.fr/books?id=epPhgMbrmdMC&lpg=PR48&dq=Kannada%20English%20Dictionary%20abbreviation&hl=fr&pg=PR48#v=onepage&q&f=true   and let me know if it works

Comment: In Merriam-Webster dictionaries for the first half of the 20th century, _p. pr._ meant "participle present," _p. p._ meant "participle past," and _pret._ meant "preterit." But there appears not to have been agreement throughout the field of lexicography on standard abbreviations for the various parts of speech and other explanatory or descriptive terms. Given the absence of any real consensus on abbreviations, the author's failure to provide a list of long forms for the abbreviations he employs imposes a rather grave limitation on the usefulness of his work.

Comment: @JoBedard Yes, that link works. Unfortunately, the abbreviations are nothing like in the book I have. It looks like there's no easy answer to this question and that I'll have to research each new abbreviation I don't understand as they come up.

Comment: Ironically, Julius de Lanerolle, who wrote the prefatory note to the 1941 edition of Geiger's _Etymological Glossary of the Sinhalese Language_, observes that "I have also added a list of Abbreviations indicating the languages referred to in the book. The other ordinary abbreviations used by the author were considered to be too well known to need a similar list." Moral of story: Don't omit lists of abbreviations from a reference work on grounds that the abbreviations are "too well known" to need one.

Comment: @SvenYargs When I build my time machine I'll be sure to tell him!

Comment: To save others some time, the book in question has been digitized by Google and can be found at http://books.google.com/books?id=FTi9geZ1WbEC , and a good portion is available for preview.  Perhaps it would help to collect as many of the abbreviations which can be found, and then Google for the set?

Comment: @SvenYargs I have seen this happen many times before, where the author has failed to include an explanation of abbreviations in a reference book from a long time ago. I believe I’ve even answered questions here about such. What might be even worse here is that the writer himself was German, and so may think “commonplace” a philological working-set that is different than the ones more commonly known in English, particularly a layman’s English of the early 21st century. I’d like to think no one writing today would ever omit an element so important to deciphering their work, but you never know.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97634

Comment: Nice find @DanBron! Mine even has a price label from the same place inside (although mine was originally Rs545).

Answer (score 3):

sq., sqq.   sequentia   f., ff.     [und] folgende [Seite]; [und] folgende [Seiten]
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_lateinischer_Abkurzungen

however noun f. is Feminine substansive (noun - in German capitalized)

ie following (page or ff pages) common in German and because of the word similarity , why explain!

s. singular - much more important to a German but he may also have used 
s. as neuter (sesslich in German). Sinhalese has apparently 3 gender cases

http://www.languagesgulper.com/eng/Sinhalese.html

in general, I suggest to look for Latin abbrev. based around English, and what is possible within Sinhala

Comment: See link posted by @DanBron Look at http://books.google.com/books?id=FTi9geZ1WbEC page 22, entries 343 & 344 for examples of st. f. and st. ff. "f." could be following (single) word, "ff." could be following (multiple) words. I haven't seen any examples to contradict this but I still don't know what "st." stands for, only that it's marking plural forms. It could possibly be the adjective form of the noun as explained in Teach Yourself Sinhalese by A.W.L. Silva, p 180: _mala_ flower, _mal_ flowers, _gaha_ tree, _gas_ trees, _mal gaha_ flowering tree. He mentions the plural nominative case.

Comment: In the link you provide go about half way down to Morphology and compare **gender** with **number**. You'll see why number makes much more sense than gender for "st." "book" _pota_ (p 155, entry 1724) is not going to change from masculine to feminine (_poti_?) but from singular to plural (_pot_).

Comment: I just found out that he uses "fem." for feminine. Page 195, entry 2945: _horā_, s., st. f. _hora_, thief, robber, rogue; fem. _hera_. Does anyone have a really good guess what "st." means? I can't think of any synonyms for "plural" that would abbreviate to "st".

Comment: @user3306356 It was lovely of you to award some bounty points, however, the only part of this answer I can agree with is that "f"/"ff" is following (although word/words rather than page/pages). So far the most useful contribution has been the comment from Erik Kowal, although I would still only agree with about half of his guesses.