# How to refer to several paragraphs or articles §§ in law or pages in books

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

As a non-native English speaker, I came to the problem, how to refer to several articles or pages in law for an essay I have to write.

I did some research here and found the page [Is there reference material for dictionary abbreviations used in the first half of the 20th century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186341/is-there-reference-material-for-dictionary-abbreviations-used-in-the-first-half/189211#189211) which was only partially helpful to me as the Wikipedia-webpage did not exist anymore and a similar one, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_lateinischer_Abk%C3%BCrzungen only offered Latin terms.

So I refuse to use abbreviations and I am not satisfied with the results of translators like DeepL, that say "**and following**" is to use. It seems to me like word-for-word translation without considering common speech.

So, please help me to replace "and following": (Thanks in advance)

Please refer to code of law page XYZ "and following" - especially to Article ABC "and following".

Comment: Hello, romeoyankee. I'm afraid I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. The fact that you 'have to write' this essay means that you are writing under the style restraints of a specific institution. Different institutions prefer different styles, so you need to check with someone in the particular institution whose authority you have accepted for the duration of your course. As @tchrist has said, 'Questions about [specific, especially when not specified here] style guides are off-topic [on ELU].'

Comment: In the US, style issues for legal documents are generally governed by [*The Bluebook: A Uniform System of Citation*](https://www.legalbluebook.com), so if you don't have some other style specified (by your teacher or editor) your best bet would be to get your hands on a copy. If you're pretty sure of the style you need but can't access a manual or find info by searching online, I think if you specify the style and explain what you've already done to try to figure it out your question could be on topic at Writing.SE, maybe here, too.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I paid much attention to the rules of the site and even more time doing research on how to solve my problem. I have no clue, how to be more specific and I definetly tried to ask the question as useful as possible for every one. Since the institution I am writing for has decided to use British English and has no futher restrictions as the norms and standards of the EU (espacially UK of course), I thought this would be the right place to answer this question. If I am wrong, close this thread.

Comment: Sorry to point this out, and it cannot be "several articles or pages…". Very simply, "Articles" and "pages" cannot be related except by coincidence and cannot be compared at all.

To attempt to do so would be like attempting to compare books to chapters or chapters to pages… pure nonsense.

Comment: I can not see any connection to cross references and reference lists in your suggestion.